# Create height-map/displacement map for simple object like baseball cap

Tags: displacement, height-map, distort

Is there any way to create height map for some simple objects like baseball cap? (only part of the image is enough -the front printing area of cap shown below)

I want to print/warp some image on some object(cap,mug,...) with displacement map. Kind of custom design for people to upload different images like the below image of 'deer'.

***below is what the displacement map will used for.*** The effect is what I got from some website.

input image
[image: input image]

using displacement map to get the result below
[image: using displacement map to get the result below]

may be helpful to explain what I need

[image: may be relevant]

An examples of what I need:

[image]

I have the user image which need to be distorted

[image]

Using software like Photoshop or Python code, I could get the final result of distorted image like below. ***Similar to Print/Warp something on a 3d object.***

[image]

Comment: Can you also add an example of what type of output you need? Is this for 3d parallax mapping that is currently so popular on social media?

Comment: Jackdaw, example added. May be different from 3d parallax mapping, I just need do 2d displacement map. :)

Comment: It should be possible to just add an emissive material with the texture coordinates used as color input. You will need to make sure that the color management profile is linear so the data is retained (I think that this can be done by setting the Display Device to None).  I can't try this out without the exact setup of the output.

Comment: How to add an emissive material? I am new to 3d software like blender. ..

Comment: I suggest that you watch trough the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hgfto0JM_jA&t=2s . It's for 2.79 but should transfer fairly well to 2.8.